# Help me add parameters to a function that draws a pattern

Tags: c++

***Please help me answer this question , void Function with parameters. I do not understand it very well***

I want to write a program so that the user can input both characters that form the pattern

I need to define two  (characters) variables  which are  (star) and  (next),  the statement  must  include three parameters – one that will be an  (int)  for the pattern

and  two that will be (characters)  for the character to display the pattern.

I have to change the  function  (drawpattern)  to have three values parameters

an (int)  parameter indicating the size  of the pattern  and two  (characters) indicating the character that will be used to display the pattern .

input  (4) for size, (Y) for the character to be used  to start the pattern  and  (+) for the second and every alternate group

This is what I have done so far and I do not now if is okay:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void drawPattern(int size, char start, char next)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= size; j++)
        {
            if ((i / size) % 3 == 0)
                if ((j / size3) % 3 == 0)
                    cout << '4';
                else
                    cout << 'Y';
            else
                if ((j / size) % 3 == 0)
                    cout << '+';
                else
                    cout << '4';
        }
}  
int main ()
{
    int size;
    char start, next;

    cout << "Please enter number ( 4 ) for the size of the pattern : ";
    cin >> size;

    cout << " Now enter leter ( Y ) to start the pattern: ";
    cin >> start;

    cout << "Lastly enter the ( + ) for the other pattern: ";
    cin >> size;

    cout << " This is the output pattern: " << endl;
    drawPattern(size, start, next);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I added a code block around your code, but now you need to fix the indenting.  No one can read that.

Comment: Why are you reading into `size` twice?

Comment: It's bad enough that we need to fix your formatting, but it's even worse when you then break it again. What I'd recommend: 1) Fix the the ___question's title___ to say, in one terse and meaningful sentence, what problem(s) you have. 2) Fix your program's ___indentation___. That indentation makes my eyes bleed. I refuse to look at such an abomination. 3) Try to break that wall of text describing your problem into ___intelligibly sentences___. I know this isn't easy for non-natives (I'm a non-native, too), but breaking it into smaller sentences would likely be easier for you as well.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking. Does the code produce incorrect results and you don't know why, or does it produce correct results but you don't understand how it works?

Comment: It hurts seeing this as community wiki

Comment: I bravely edited the topic title to something that (hopefully) describes the question better.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are hard coding your output in the drawPattern function and ignoring the actual input from the user. I think you should probably replace the 'Y' and '+' with the corresponding argument passed to the function, since I'm pretty sure the professor would not be happy about hard coded values.

Comment: the program is compiling but I do not know if  I type the correct code as it says in the question above

Comment: I'm not certain you understand the question completely. It's asking you that for an input number X (whatever that number may be) you have 2 characters (a first and a second). It looks like they want you to write a program that starts with the first character and alternates between the first and second characters until you have done it X times...so if you input 8, X, and F it would look like 'XFXFXFXF'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

At line 11, you have a typo. It says `size3` where it should say `size`.

You are also making a logical mistake.

This code

```
if ((i / size) % 3 == 0)
```

is wrong in concept. At least as the code is written now. Normally you would write like this:

```
if (i % 3 == 0)
```

This if statement will be true every third row. The `%` (modulu) calculates the remainder of the integer (whole number) division `firstnumber / secondnumber`. If you have a sequence of `i` going from 0 to 10, this is what `i % 3` outputs

```
i:    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
i%3:  0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1   2   0   1
```

As you can see, `i % 3 == 0` is `true` when i is divisible by 3.

Your code does something different. Let's say `size` = 10. Then you calculate the (integer) division `i / size`. Lastly you calculate `(i / size) % 3`. However `i` is always less than `size`, except at the last turn of the loop. Let's look at the values again:

```
i:      0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
size:   10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10  10
i/size: 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Since the value of `i / size` only changes once, the calculation `(i / size) % 3` is meaningless.

Comment: If it makes sense, please click the up button to vote for this answer. You should probably NOT accept this answer, since I have not fully solved your problem.